# How to save a New Xml file using app.config?

Tags: c#

I have to save a file with the help of app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appsetting>
    <add key ="filename" value ="abc.xml"></add>
    <add key="filepath" value ="C:\\Users\\saket.parasar.jha"></add>
  </appsetting>
</configuration>
```

My code for saving the xml file to the prescribed path-:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        //XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        //doc.AppendChild(docNode);

        XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("products");
        doc.AppendChild(productsNode);


        {
            XmlNode productNode = doc.CreateElement("product");
            XmlAttribute productAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
            productAttribute.Value = "1";
            productNode.Attributes.Append(productAttribute);
            productsNode.AppendChild(productNode);

            XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            nameNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Java"));
            productNode.AppendChild(nameNode);

            XmlNode priceNode = doc.CreateElement("Price");
            priceNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Free"));
            productNode.AppendChild(priceNode);

            AddUpdateAppSettings("filename", "abc.xml");


        }
    }
static void AddUpdateAppSettings(string key, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
                if (settings[key] == null)
                {
                    settings.Add(key, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    settings[key].Value = value;
                }
                configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
            }
            catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings");
            }
        }
```

I have to write that xml file to C:\Users\saket.parasar.jha" using c#...pls help me out, I am new to this topic.I tried a lot but was nt able to save that file.

Comment: And what is the error you receive?

Comment: On a totally unrelated topic, I think `"C:\\Users\\saket.parasar.jha"` is not a very good place for saving file. First, if Windows language is not en, this path will be invalid. Second, that folder is the root of all user directories, and usually not used for individual files. You can use AppData if you want to save app specific files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can never modify app.config file programmatically. The settings inside are never to be changed while your app is running. These settings are like "pre-launch". If you need any settings modificable by a user, use **Settings File** (*Add > New Item > General > Settings File*), the one with the extension *.settings. Also, I don't see you trying to get your settings from your configuration file, you're only saving them there (but you can't do that, the reason is above).
After you get your path properly, you can save your file there.

P.S.: App.config is not allowed to be modified, because it sits in the same directory as the app (with modified name like MyApplication.exe.config); when you app is installed on a destination system, the destination directory will most likely be "Program Files". As you understand, any attempt to modify the config will require elevated privileges (like an administrator's). That means your app is VERY user unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save your XmlDocument? something like

```
doc.Save("C:\\Users\\saket.parasar.jha\\abc.xml");
```

Comment: I have to save the file using app.config file such that application can be used in other computer too